# GridView Customization

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, .net-3.5, controltemplate

I have a grid view with more than one control (ie. a DropDownList and a TextBox)

How can I bind the DropDownList in the gridview and how do I insert an add button in the footer of the gridview

I have found a few ways to do this but they are confusing and I am not sure about the performance of them.

Comment: It seems you are asking for code to be written over here which might not sound great, come with the exact difficulties you are facing

Comment: the problem i face is about create new row with the control(empedded) without drawback in the performce.

Comment: Whats the problem with grid.Rows.Add()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: [Adding an insert row to GridView](http://geekswithblogs.net/casualjim/articles/51360.aspx).

It provides a full code sample that is easy to follow.  In terms of performance, adding a row will require a postback but you can wrap your GridView in an UpdatePanel and very easily have a seemingly AJAXified GridView.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a flexible control of the layout and still get all the power of GridView, I suggest that you look into ListView. You have control over the template for layout, footer, item and etc. which sounds like what you need. Here is the comparison between ListView, GridView and others.

http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/09/06/comparing-listview-with-gridview-datalist-and-repeater.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can keep searching in `Google` and find good example's.

*These links may help you:*

> - Create Custom Column(like DropDown):
>     [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/GridViewComboBoxField.aspx), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228046.aspx)
> - Also for Custom-Footer look fo this links: [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913264/adding-link-button-to-footer-of-gridview-in-asp-net), [ASP-Forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1133918.aspx/1)

Comment: **`CodeProject link`** help you directly in *`custom column`*, and **`stackoverFlow link`** help you to create *`footer for grid with link-button`*.